# The advantage of having another table for multiple product images?

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing

This is the product table in my MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_products` (
  `productId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productSku` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `productDescription` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `extraSpecification` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `productPrice` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MRP` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `productImage` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pageTitle` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `productKeywords` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `metaDescription` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `dateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `addedBy` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `productName` (`productName`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `productName_2` (`productName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=174 ;
```

You see, I have a column for product image

```
  `productImage` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
```

it saves the path to product image in a folder 'data' on the server and works fine.

The problem, need to have at least three images per product. Saw a few ecommerce database structure and realized that most of them have a different table 'product_images' for storing multiple images per product.

Can someone please explain me the concept and more importantly the **advantage** of having another table altogether and how can I get it done.

Comment: You're asking us to explain the basic concept of relational databases. No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawback of using the same table is that you need a column for every image, so you create three new columns (or use a comma separated list) for up to three images, and the client then says they want 4 or 5 images, so you're constantly having to add new columns (or increase the length of the existing column) as the number of images they want increases..... using a separate table allows for growth without further change to database structure or to your code (after the initial work to support it)

Comment: ah ha, get it. Thank you Mark, accepting your answer wish I get a working example online to show me how it is done. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 3):

Advantage of having separate table to store product images are you can store N number of images in that table. other solution is you can store multiple image in comma separated manner in one field. this method has one biggest disadvantage as you first need to separate the data by comma and then iterate the data. and while you update the data you first need to get already stored string from database then update the string with latest one and this case will be worst when you perform delete. for delete you won't be able to rectify easily which path or image needs to be remove.If you are storing path then you need to perform many string operation to remove it and make sure other string part won't get hurt. there will be chance of losing your data while update or insert new images as each time you need to get old data and then append new one. so different table is easy to handle for update or insert new value and you will have one unique "id" to play with and you can perform insert,update,delete easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the same image to multiple products, you need a table for the images, and an extra table for the n-m assginment. This would be the technique if you have an image-manager in your program where you can upload and manage your images separately:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_image` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productImage` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_products_images` (
  `productid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `imageid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (productid, imageid),
  FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES tbl_products(productId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (imageid) REFERENCES tbl_image(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

In the table `tbl_products_images` you can store the ids of the product and the associated image.

To fetch the images of a product you can use a simple join:

```
SELECT productImage FROM tbl_image i INNER JOIN tbl_products_images pi ON pi.imageid=i.id WHERE pi.productid=33;
```

... where `33` is the id of the product.

If you have a simpler scenario, where an uploaded image belongs to exactly one product you just need an image table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_image` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productImage` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `productid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES tbl_products(productId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

With this you can create as many images as you like and associate them with a product using the `productid` attribute. This is how you fetch the images for a product with id `33`:

```
SELECT productImage FROM tbl_image i WHERE productid=33;
```

With the `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the table definitions, you assure that the images entries are deleted, when their corresponding products are deleted.

Comment: you said "If you want to assign the same image to multiple products" but I am looking to assign multiple images per product.

Comment: I meant it vice versa. But anyway I made an update of my answer to address a simpler scenario